# Customizing windows 7 login with Credential Providers

Tags: c#, api, authentication, windows-7

Usually, Windows 7 uses username and password to authenticate the user.I need to customize this feature.I would like to write a windows service that will allow some external device or authentication provider to log a user into windows.For example, a finger print reader can log a user into windows via fingerprint instead of password.

So I am trying find a C# API for this purpose(like `GINA.DLL`).

Can anyone point me in the right direction in terms of what I need and where I should start researching how to make such a thing?

**UPDATED:**
I have gone through following link.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx. It contains the information. But examples are in C++.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying find a C# API for this purpose

[Do not use high level languages, libraries, frameworks, virtual machines or runtimes in core operating system processes](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;841927&Product=NETFrame).

Comment: I read the article..Its true.. but someone told me it is possible to do with a c# API...

Comment: this link might be help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917790/a-gina-replacement-in-a-net-language